# how can I do Apache kafka to spark streaming and get msg in rdd PySpark

Tags: apache-kafka, pyspark, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to streaming from Kafka to spark.

1. Installed both kafka and spark
2. Started zookeeper with default
3. properties config Started kafka server with default properties
   config
4. Started kafka producer Started kafka consumer Sent message
   from producer to consumer. 
   Works fine.

   but I don't know How to send spark rdd.
   I trying to solve this from 3 days but didn't get any output.

   because I am new in spark kafka.

   I want send producer msg to spark rdd.

   I have setup spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7 and kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.
   Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: you can see the example here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py

Comment: I already saw this .